# 404 Custom Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, http-status-code-404

Hello I am trying to do a redirect if the response is a 404 but it is not working as expected, can you experts see the issue?. It still goes to the generic 404

in my Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (Response.Status == "404 Not Found")
        {
            string notFound = "~/custom_notfound.aspx";
            Response.Redirect(notFound);
        } 

}
```

UPDATE

Tried so far

```
(Response.Status == "404 Not Found")
(Response.Status == "404")
(Response.StatusCode == 404)
```

Comment: Did you mean to put  `Response.Redirect(notFound );`?

Comment: ahh sorry typo when posting but still have the issue. Thank you

Comment: can you try (Response.Status == 404) (i am not sure it will work but give it a try )

Comment: tried.. still ir doesnt pick it upm and it is (Response.StatusCode == 404) because (Response.Status == "expects a string") and also tried (Resonse.Status == "404") and tried (Response.Status == "404 not found") neither worked

Comment: (Response.status == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use the web.config customerrors section - [as shown here](http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs)

e.g. In the system.web section,

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/custom_error.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/custom_notfound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think BeginRequest could know about 404 errors.  Try implementing Application_Error instead.  Check to see if Server.GetLastError() is an HttpException, and if so, check the status.

Answer (score 2):

You could add to your web.config to do this redirection, you don't need to use `Application_BeginRequest` to handle this.

See this [ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/68137/how-to-configure-a-web-config-file-to-allow-custom-404-handling-while-still-displ).

If you can't use the web.config then I would set your startup page to one that doesn't exist, put a breakpoint in your BeginRequest, debug the app and look at the request to see how to determine it is a 404.  That would be much easier to determine the optimal solution.

Looking into this some more, there is a [HttpStatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx) that is used in the HttpWebResponse class.  So it may make sense to use a different override of the Application to get the default response, and then check it's status against the Enum.

Comment: In any case, for some reason they want it done in the asax, which would be the way to do it there?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="File" >
     <remove statusCode="404" />
     <remove statusCode="500" />
     <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" />
     <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" />
   </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```